# How to Call model function as validation rule

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a problem using the form_validation library with CodeIgniter 3.x :

I want to use a model function as a validation rule for an input. When I submit my form, it seems that the function isn't called at all. [According to the user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validation#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule), here's the way I do it from my controller :

```
if($this->input->post() !== false) 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'username', //the post value to check
            'User Name',
            array(
                'trim',
                'required',
                array($this->user_model, 'checkUserName') // i want to call checkUserName from the user_model model
            )
        );
```

I don't understand why it doesn't even calls the checkUserName function in the user_model : does anyone has an idea ?

**[EDIT]** : I saw the source code for the set_rules() function in system/libraries/form_validation.php. It seems that if the third parameter is not a string, it does nothing, so I cannot call a model function. userguide is not uptodate ?
Here's the lines of code that I found from form_validation :

```
// No fields? Nothing to do...
    if ( ! is_string($field) OR  ! is_string($rules) OR $field == '')
    {
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Have you load model file in your constructor and make sure you are  running PHP 5.3+ !!

Comment: Yes : I'm running php 5.6.10 and the model is loaded in the constructor of my controller.

Comment: Have you got any error??

Comment: Log threshold is defined to 4 in my config.php file : nothing suspect, even in th php error log. It seems the form_validation just ignores this rule

Comment: Have you code enter into this condition `if($this->input->post() !== false) `

Comment: Yes : I'm doing it, then I use var_dump to see what is received, I load the form_validation library then I start to se the rules. Something strange is that all set_rules calls where I use an array for specify the rules are ignored. When I remove the array as the third parameter and reset to something like 'trim|required', but i cant' call my model function this way.

Answer (score 0):

if you are checking username for not to duplicate used the builtin function `is_unique['table.field]`.
**table**:name of table.
**field**: is name of field that is going to be check.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', User Name, 'is_unique['users.username]');
```

this will check dbtable users for field Username.if the provided username is find it will return *error username not unique*.


this is `is_unique()` function defined in form_validation class :

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
    {
        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field);
        return isset($this->CI->db)
            ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;
    }
```

if you really want to call your own custom function then ...
the best is to extend the form_validation class:as follow.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    protected $CI;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function check_user_name($str)
    {
      //here you codes goes eg.$this->CI->db->get_where(); etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to check if the username is unique : I have to check if it exists and check some others settings, so I could not use this. But as I said in my post edit, it's strange that user guide speaks about a feature that seems to be not implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
'premium_dates' => [
        'field'  => 'premium_dates',
        'label'  => 'Premium dates',
        'rules'  => [
            'trim',
            ['validate_premium_dates', function () {
                return $this->Properties_seasons_model->validate_premium_dates();
            }],
        ],
        'errors' => [
            'validate_premium_dates' => 'Premium dates enabled. Please choose at least one Premium Date.',
        ],
    ];
```